# "Submit for review" specific build version in itunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

How to "submit for review" another build of the App , if I have already submitted an old one before in itunesconnect?

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled for a day or so on two issues until I have figured it out.

First I wanted to "remove from review" a previous build that I have submitted into review previously, I have searched all over the place to remove it from review button.

> It Appears that Apple take several hours up to a day to post the link under the submitted version page
>   When posted you will find it under "Version Information", you can use to remove the current build from review.

Secondly, I wanted to submit another build for review, but couldn't find how to remove the current build attached with the current version.

> It appears that to remove the current build , you should go to the version number page  under "Versions" , then goes to "Build" section, you will see your App icon with build info.
>   Hover with the mouse on the icon and delete icon will be there to disattach that build from the current version page and you can attach you specified build with you current version and can now submit it for review.

Note: The delete button will be only active when you have "no submitted build for review".